# How to isolate styles per session with bundles

Tags: css, asp.net, session, bundles

I have in my application ASP.net different styles that are loaded by bundles according to the configuration of each user.
When I change login in the same browser, it works correctly, for each user a different style is seen, but the problem is:
The idea is that the application is concurrent for several users and each has its session, I observed using different browsers that when logging in and loading the bundle for one user modifies the style of the session in another browser.
Is there any way to isolate styles between sessions?

Using two types of SessionStates, for an On Premise environment InProc, for a cloud environment using Azure Redis Cache
The bundles I declare according to the recommendation

```
  bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/bundles/Css").Include(hojaestilo,
                                                             "~/Content/jquery.calculator.alt.css",
                                                             "~/Content/jquery.treeview.min.css"))

        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
        "~/Scripts/reports.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
        "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
        "~/Scripts/cultures/globalize.culture.es-ES.js",
        "~/Scripts/gestion.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.min.js"))

        bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/bundles/CssJs").Include(hojaestilojs))
        bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/bundles/Estilos_imprimir").Include("~/Content/estilos_imprimir.css"))

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
```

Thanks

Comment: A possible solution that has occurred to me is to put a suffix to the names of the bundles with the SessionID, but I do not know if it was a good practice.